# Location of ColdFusion admin

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

We had an issue where the CF service went down, and a restart of the service did not come up, so we rebooted the machine. After the system reboot, the CF service came back up just fine, but we now have a nasty watermark on our PDF reports saying:

> Adobe ColdFusion Developer/Trial Edition. Not for Production Use

We have the proper licenses, but cannot locate the CFIDE/Administrator anywhere on the webserver. Are we going about this incorrectly? Could the issue be something else?

Comment: When you say you can't find CFIDE/Administrator anywhere, do you mean on the file system or do you mean you can't access it from a Web browser?

Answer (score 6):

Go to \ColdFusion11\cfusion\lib and locate license.properties. Open this file in notepad or wordpad and ensure that the ColdFusion 11 Serial number is there. If not, then please type in your license key (in front of sn= ) and Restart the ColdFusion services.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the new license key on "System Information" page. It is on right side corner of cf admin page.